# Scopus outward citations?

Tags: r, api, http, bibliography, citations

You can get the inward citations for a SCOPUS citation fairly easily:

```
http://www.scopus.com/inward/citedby.url?partnerID=HzOxMe3b&scp=84881394200&origin=inward
```

How do you get the outward citations?

*tip:* `http://www.scopus.com/outward/citedby.url?partnerID=HzOxMe3b&scp=84881394200&origin=outward` does not work.

Comment: Unsure why this question was downvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have sufficiently high reputation to comment, so I have to post this as an answer instead.

What do you mean by outward citations?  The contents of the bibliography?  That shows up if you scroll down a bit, just past the section with ISSN and DOI and the like:  http://www.scopus.com/record/display.url?eid=2-s2.0-84881394200

From there it looks like you can click "Page" and then save the list as a CSV.

You can also grab a XML version using the API, but based on the question I assume that's not what you're trying to do.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: As I stated in the first line, I don't have sufficiently high reputation to comment.  I currently have 1 reputation; when I click on "add a comment" a pop-up box appears stating that I must have 50 reputation to comment.